# cron alternative php tip

Tags: php, cron

i got a file  `fetch.php`

for now i am manually calling it from a bookmark once a day to execute the script.

i want to set kind of like a cron..that just goes to `fetch.php` once a day..

is it possible..

the `fetch.php` file has a html and bunch of javascript thats why cron doesn't work..

thanks... if you need clarification let me know..

Comment: well - remove all html and js. who do you show it?

Comment: Seriously, what's the Javascript for? JS is only important for presentational purposes, it has no inherent functionality you can't replicate in PHP. If you don't need the presentation layer, why do you depend on HTML and Javascript? Write all the functionality in PHP and you'll have no problem setting it up as a proper cron job.

Answer (score 2):

in the crontab you can run it with a [lynx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx) command

example :

```
lynx -dump http://your.website.com > /dev/null
```

#### EDIT:

the problem is that lynxs not run javascript.

so you need to find a command line web browser that support javascript , it Not quite simple.

check a '[links](http://links.twibright.com/features.php)' or 'w3m'

read more about in this post :

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/is-there-a-browser-command-line-tool-for-testing-javascript-websites-359260/

Comment: I doubt lynx does Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript has to be executed, it sounds like it *has* to be run in a browser. Unless you're willing to add a lot more complexity, I'd go with one of these routes:

- Use cron or Task Scheduler to launch the page in a web browser. Use javascript to have the page close itself (its tab) after it's loaded.
  cron: `* 9 * * * /usr/bin/firefox "http://localhost/cron.php"` (may or may not work)
  JavaScript: `function all_done() { window.close(); }`
- Leave a tab open 24/7 and use [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/) or something similar.